# SQL Server: How to select rows that were inserted on the same day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, between

I have a loop, that goes through some entries. In the loop I'm getting creation date and I need to find if there were entries inserted on the same day. So for example if `creation date = 2011-08-31 21:19:14.345`, I need to select all rows where the creation date is between `2011-08-31 00:00:00.000` and `2011-08-31 23:59:59.999`

How do I do this with SQL?

Comment: Looping is usually a poor practice, could we have some more details about what you are doing so we can point you to a better set-based way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any other schema details, and if this is SQL Server 2K8+, you could do this:

```
DECLARE @CreationDate Date = '2011-08-31';

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE CONVERT(Date, CreationDate) = @CreationDate;
```

By converting to a `date` instead of working with `datetime` you lose the time component and "normalize" how you're comparing the values.

Another way to lose the time component for comparison purposes is:

```
DECLARE @CreationDate DateTime;
SELECT @CreationDate = '2011-08-31 21:19:14.345';

SELECT @CreationDate; -- 2011-08-31 21:19:14.345
SELECT @CreationDate = CONVERT(DateTime, FLOOR(CONVERT(Float, @CreationDate)));
SELECT @CreationDate; -- 2011-08-31 00:00:00.000
```

You would use that if you don't have the `date` data type.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, that i'm using MSSQL. No date type :(

Comment: @Sergejs: MSSQL **does** have the `date` type, probably just not your version. See my revised answer and please tag the question with the version you're working with.

Comment: Be aware that with this method, SQL Server will not perform an index seek if the CreationDate column is indexed. This may or may not make a huge difference depending on number of rows in the table. Use the greater than and less than method if performance is poor. More info on use of functions in the where clause and table/index scans: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/

Answer (score 4):

In order to catch all the times in that day do this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE DateCreated >= @TheDate AND DateCreated < DATEADD(day, 1, @TheDate)
```

Where `@TheDate` must be the pure date without time. It works even when `DateCreated` has a time part very close to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable  
WHERE   
DAY(TDATE) = DAY(CreationDate)  
AND  
MONTH(TDATE) = MONTH(CreationDate)  
AND  
YEAR(TDATE) = YEAR(CreationDate)
```